# Job aborted when writing table using different cluster on Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I have two clusters on databricks and i used one (cluster1) to write a table on the datalake. I need to use the other cluster (cluster2) to schedule the job in charge of writing this table. However, this error occurs:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o344.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 
in stage 3740.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3740.0 (TID 
113976, 10.246.144.215, executor 13): org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: 
CREATE failed with error 0x83090aa2 (Forbidden. ACL verification failed. Either the 
resource does not exist or the user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.). 
[7974c88e-0300-4e1b-8f07-a635ad8637fb] failed with error 0x83090aa2 (Forbidden. 
ACL verification failed. Either the resource does not exist or the user is not authorized 
to perform the requested operation.).
```

From the "Caused by" message it seems that I do not have the authorization to write on the datalake, but if i change the table name it successfully write the df onto the datalake.

I am trying to write the table with the following command:

```
df.write \
    .format('delta') \
    .mode('overwrite')\
    .option('path', path)\
    .option('overwriteSchema', "true")\
    .saveAsTable(table_name)
```

I tried to drop the table and rewriting it using the cluster2 but this doesn't work, as if the location on the datalake is already occupied: only using cluster1 I can write in that location.

In the past I simply changed the table name as a workaround, but this time I need to keep the old name.

How can I solve this? Why the datalake is related to the cluster with which i wrote the table?

Comment: Please edit your post to include more detailed error message - especially look for "Caused by" lines. Right now it's impossible to understand why this happens

Answer (score 1):

The issue was cause by different Service Principals used for the two clusters.

To solve the problem I had to drop the table and **remove the path in the datalake** with cluster1. Then, I could write the table again using cluster2.

The command to delete the path is:

```
rm -r 'adl://path/to/table'
```